# Fetch result from Raw SQL in asp.net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

in controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empno = {0}", 3195);
    var ret = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql).ToList();

     // I want to fetch above query result here...
     // Above query returns more than 1 rows and more than 1 column
     // Like ret.Column1(row0).value

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

how can I fetch result in the same function.. i need to perform some calculation here and saved the result in database again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do like this. Create a ViewModel:

```
public class EmployeeVM
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string EmployeeName {get;set;}
}
```

action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    string sql = string.Format("SELECT Id,EmployeeName FROM emp WHERE empno = {0}", 3195);
    var ret = db.Database.SqlQuery<EmployeeVM>(sql).ToList();

     /
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Remember that your model properties name should match the column name of the table, as in my case Id and EmployeeName property are  mataching with column name.

Comment: Thanks, can you also tell me if I use ToArray instead of ToList and How?

Comment: you should use list in my opinion of you want to use array simply replace ToList with ToArray

Comment: Then how can I get value from an arrey

Comment: same way as you get from List